# Attribute Selector in microstrategy Dashboards

Tags: analytics, microstrategy

Suppose I have a dashboard with a report embedded in it in Microstrategy.

Is there any way by which I could let the user vary a single attribute while the dashboard is running.

By this, I mean, that the user should be able to choose which attribute is being displayed on the dashboard,

For instance let the report have a structure

Attribute 1 | Attribute 2 | Attribute 3

Can I let the user , through a drop down box , change this in real time to

Attribute 1 | Attribute 2 | Attribute 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there aren't too many options, you could set up a Panel Stack, with panels containing versions of the grid with the appropriate attribute visible.

Then it would appear that your Panel Stack selector was changing the grid (when really it's switching between different version).

Comment: There are around 11 options. hence I was looking for an easier approach. But I guess that's the only option

Answer (score 0):

Yon can use an object prompt in your report to select attributes on the fly.

Comment: That's going to require a re-execution though, not really "on the fly".

Comment: Yes. But in question it was no where mentioned at that it should be on the fly. Due to reason i suggested this approach. And if you have too many combinations panel stack approach will not work.

Comment: "change this in real time"